# Why Azure SQL clustered index is so extremely big?

Tags: database, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

When I compare index sizes in our MS Azure DB, there is something weird.

I have two different DB tables (let's say tableA and tableB). Both has PRIMARY CLUSTERED INDEX on single BIGINT column.

tableA has around 350 000 records, and tableB has (slightly more) 380 000 records.

But index on tableA is 1100 Megabytes in size, and index on tableB is just around 100 Megabytes.

Can someone explain why is this happening ? Where could be the problem ?

PS: The index size was measured with script published here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/19/10051969.aspx

Comment: have you checked how fragmented the index is?

Comment: The clustered index **is the data** - the leaf level pages of the clustered index **are the data pages** - the entire data!

Comment: ok. i'll change it: have you checked how fragmented is your data? because if the leaf contains the data, fragmentation can still blow it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustered index size show the actual size of the table. That's why in the blog, in query is condition:

```
WHERE type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
```